# How to return only rows with maximum values

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my SQL Server table:

```
CREATE TABLE weather (id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                      place varchar(100) NULL,
                      description varchar(100) NULL);
```

The place column contains a city name.

The description contains the weather description (e.g. "sunny").

Multiple values are inserted per hour per city. Now I want to know what is the "avarage" weather description, based on my collected data.

A result set could look like this:

```
place     description
---------------------
london    sunny
berlin    rainy
```

Here is my SQL fiddle with sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ee736/2/0

My current statement, which is not completed yet:

```
SELECT 
    w.place, w.description, COUNT(w.description) DESCRIPTION_COUNT
FROM
    weather w 
GROUP BY 
    w.place, w.description
```

This statement misses to group the place and find the maximum count on the description. I guess it can be solved by using `HAVING` and subselects.

Comment: Do you wish to retrieve the data for records which have maximum occurance of description for each city

Comment: @Kapil Exactly, that's what I need. For my SQL fiddle it should be "Boston|mostly cloudy" and second row "London|sunny"

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
SELECT top(1) with ties w.place , w.description, COUNT(w.description) DESCRIPTION_COUNT
 from weather w 
 group by w.place, w.description
 order by row_number() over (partition by place order by COUNT(w.description) desc);
```

Comment: Can you please explain the extraordinary things like `top(1) with ties` or `order by row_number() over (partition..`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql     Plus, MS Sql allows `row_number()`  in `ORDER BY` clause of `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the "mode" -- the most common value:

```
select w.*
from (select w.city, w.description, count(*) as cnt
             row_number() over (partition by city order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from weather w
      group by w.city, w.description
     ) w
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Gordon: I just tried to correct your answer to let it works (as I think it was correct as main idea).  Obviously feel free to delete, edit, or anything you want to do with my edit.